# ¿Como funcionan los arrays con punteros en C?

Tags: c, array, lista, punteros

hace poco me dieron un código en lenguaje C para seguir desarrollando un lenguaje de programacion nuevo y me encontre con unas instrucciones que me llamaron la atención de como declarar un array y usarlo, pero que que ya las había visto antes. Adjunto un ejemplo de la situacion en código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *lista = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int *));

    lista[0] = 1;
    lista[1] = 2;
    lista[2] = 3;
    printf("%d, %d, %d", lista[0], lista[1], lista[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Nose si alguien me podria explicar como funcionan los arrays de esta manera con punteros ya que no me lo puedo imaginar, porque supuestamente la variable lista contiene la direccion de memoria donde esta almacenado un entero, pero porque yo puedo guardar una lista ahi?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *lista = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int *));
```

Este es un ejemplo perfecto de algo que no se debe hacer en C.

Esa línea reserva espacio para un único puntero de tipo `int`. ¿el problema? Que habría que reservar espacio para `int` ... ¿pero... por qué? Básicamente porque en arquitecturas de 32 bits, tanto `int` como `int*` ocupan 4 bytes... pero en 64 bits `int` ocupa 4 bytes mientras que `int*` ocupará 8... no estás reservando el espacio que necesitas sino otro diferente... si reservas de más desperdicias memoria, mientras que si reservas de menos o pisas memoria o el SO mata tu aplicación.

Pero si la reserva ya es problemática su uso no es menos dañino:

```
lista[0] = 1;
lista[1] = 2;
lista[2] = 3;
```

Como hemos visto antes se estaba reservando espacio para uno o dos `int`... aunque la idea era reservar para unicamente un elemento... y sin embargo estamos tratando la reserva como si tuviese espacio para 3 elementos... ¿ves el problema? La reserva es demasiado pequeña y ya hemos visto antes lo que puede llegar a pasar:

- Pisas memoria
- El SO mata tu aplicación para proteger la integridad de la memoria.

La reserva deberia haber sido así:

```
int *lista = (int *)malloc(3*sizeof(int));
```

Es decir, le decimos a `malloc` que nos proporcione memoria para almacenar 3 `int`.

> No se si alguien me podria explicar como funcionan los arrays de esta manera

Un programa hace uso de dos memorias diferentes: *stack* y *heap*. Realmente hay mas regiones pero esas ya son dependientes de la arquitectura hardware y software y no siempre estarán disponibles,  así que no las mencionaré aquí.

El *stack* es la pila. Los recursos almacenados aquí se destruyen de forma automática cuando ya no son necesarios... esta zona de memoria es la que antes se aprende a usar:

```
int main ()
{
  int variableEnStack = 8;
}
```

Esta zona de memoria tiene serias restricciones de espacio, por lo que no es apta para almacenar grandes colecciones de datos porque si se llena el programa dejará de funcionar.

El *heap* es la región de la memoria dinámica. La gestión de esta memoria recae en el programador. Esta memoria será tan grande como la memoria disponible en el equipo. A esta memoria se accede siempre mediante punteros:

```
int main ()
{
  int* punteroEnHeap = (int*)malloc(100*sizeof (int));

  free(punteroEnHeap);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación, bien clara y entendible. Lo mencioné porque lo vi en un código de C y me llamó mucho la atención.